# Discord bot wont log in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a very simple discord bot that won't send messages in the terminal nor the discord chat. I can't realy understand why. When I start the program the bot comes online in the discord server, but wont respond or anyting.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = '...';

client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot is Online!');
})

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === "Hello"){
        msg.reply('Hello there');
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

Comment: where is your bot hosted? what is the command are you using to start the bot?

Comment: I'm using "node ." in the terminal.

Comment: what is the name of the file for the code above? and what is written in "main" property of your package.json file?

Comment: Saw that main was not the same as the variable Discord. Thank you for your time and help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Intents: In newer versions of Discord.js, you need to specify 'intents'. Update your client initialization:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
  intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
});

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
  if (msg.content === "Hello") {
    msg.reply('Hello there');
  }
});
```